# Nested form with react and node

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

how can i implement the following form with react as front-end and node-js as back-end.
where should i implement the logic at back-end or front-end.

i have gone through articles regarding nested forms but couldn't found like this.

[image]

first form is to create new project with sub project,
a project can have many other sub project,
add sub project will be another form and that form will create a component in previous form when add button is clicked,

after all save button will create a project and add all the sub project under that project

how can this be achieved with react as front-end and node js as back-end

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would approach your problem,

1. Creating two states: project and subProjects.
2. Project name and description will be stored in the project state which will have the form of: `{ name: string, description: string}`.
3. On addSubProject() I would open a modal where you enter the subProjectName and subProjectPrice.
4. The sub projects will will be stored in the subProjects state which will have the form of: `[{name: string, price: number}, ...]`
5. On save() there will be a POST API call to an endpoint which will post a body containing the two states: `{name: project.name, description: project.description, subProjects: subProjects}`.
6. After that all you have to do in the back-end is store it in your database.

Edit:
If you want to open the sub-projects form in another page I would suggest storing both states in a global state like redux. The rest of the steps will remain the same.

Comment: sub projects should open in another page not in modal

Comment: In that case I would suggest storing both states in a global state like redux. The rest of the steps will remain the same.

Comment: Glad I could help Nihal. If you found my answer helpful an upvote would be nice.